# admob adsize for ad height

Tags: android, size, admob

I am aware of the different values that the admob size can take for example 'BANNER' which is 320 x 50, however I have seen in some apps that the ad has been made smaller, in particular squashed in height. I have tried using other values instead of 'BANNER' for adsize but it does not work. How can I make a admob banner with a lower height than 50?

THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will never get an admob banner below 50px.  If you try to put it in a layout below 50px it will register an error (check your logcat).

It is possible to display the admob as `50px` instead of the default `50dip`, with some clever editing, but im fairly sure you're not supposed to do that per the admob ToS, so I won't get into it here  :)