# Resize for smaller screen?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity, optimization

According to the android docs, these are the following ad sizes you can implement. The problem is, in my small layout, the ad is too big. Even in the smallest size:

[image]

**Is there any way to get my ads smaller than `Banner`?** It is way to big for the `Small` screen size.

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the [Android-specific documentation on AdMob banner sizes](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner):

[image: AdMob Android banner sizes]

Note how the sizes mentioned above are not quite the same as in your own table. `BANNER` is `320x50`, which may already be small enough for `small`. If not, you'll also see `SMART_BANNER` mentioned in the last row. I'll just copy-paste that section below too (it's pretty well-described), but be sure to also check out the link above, as things can (and will) change in time.

[image]

Comment: So are you suggesting to use Smart Banner?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: That depends on your requirements. If you *always* want to display an ad *and* it is okay for it to be full-width, then I'd say using the adaptive nature of `SMART_BANNER` is the way to go. If this doesn't apply and you don't mind *not* displaying an ad if there isn't enough space, then `BANNER` should be fine too. I've simply listed the options above, but it's up to you to decide which is most appropriate for your use case.

Comment: I would use `SMART_BANNER` except I'm hesitating because of this line: _specify the constant `SMART_BANNER` for the ad size. So here's the problem, and I think you can answer it. So, I have 9 layouts to target every screen in an optimal way. Is it okay to use `SMART_BANNER` for some of the layouts and something like `BANNER` for others? Will the ads still work if I specify `setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER)`? Because not all the sizes will be like that then...Let me know

Answer (score 0):

In your app where you're using admob, the SDK will request whatever size the requesting AdView was instantiated with. **If there isn't enough space on the device's screen to display the ad, nothing will be shown.**

Please check the links below :

[admob adsize for ad height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475041/admob-adsize-for-ad-height)

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner